# How to parse jsonp returned from api using python

Tags: python, json, flask, server, jsonp

I'm very new to coding, and I'm building my first web application using open REST api with python flask.
I think the api is returning jsonp which looks like this - callbackfunction{ json }; and I get from other posts that all I need to do is getting rid of this padding. However, I can't figure out at which point I should implement the stripping.

This is my code. 5th line is throwing an error "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not HTTPResponse"

```
def lookup(title):
    try:
        url = "http://www.aladin.co.kr/ttb/api/ItemSearch.aspx?ttbkey=foo&Query=bar"
        result = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(result)
        data_json = data.split("{", 1)[1].strip("}")
        return data_json

    except requests.RequestException:
        return None
```

I'm sure it's working well until 4th line. When I tried the code below, at least it returned result, though cryptic, like this.

> b'{ "version" : "20070901", "title" :
>   "\xec\x95\x8c\xeb\x9d\xbc\xeb\x94\x98 \xea\xb2\x80 ...
>   "customerReviewRank":9  } ] };'

Judging by the keys, I'm pretty sure this is the information I requested. So what can I do to fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
def lookup(title):
    try:
        url = "http://www.aladin.co.kr/ttb/api/ItemSearch.aspx?ttbkey=foo&Query=bar"
        result = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        res = result.readline()
        return res
```

Comment: Try: `res = result.decode('utf-8')` then `data = json.loads(res)`...

Comment: res = result.decode('utf-8') threw an error ('HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'decode'), but res = result.readline(), data = res.decode('utf-8) worked! Thanks a lot!!